# ANT: Get all folders matching a specific regular expression name

Tags: regex, ant

I want to get the list of folders with a by telling only a part of those folders names, smething like this:

```
Pattern: com.mypackages.*
Root folder: ${root}
Other folder: com.mypackages.p1
```

How to get all the folders matching that pattern, in ANT?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? How are you going to use the folder list?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [dirset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html)  and the include tag. It is not a regular expression, but it seems that the following is enough, for the requirements you stated.

```
<dirset dir="${root}">
  <include name="com/mypackages/*/>
</dirset>
```